# Cannot Load Rule Based Label with QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, export, rule-based

Working with QGIS, I saved my Rule Based Label as a .qml file. Opened a new Project Loaded the Shapefile and then Loaded the Style .qml file but it lost its rule based styling, x and y displacements and its Priority. Where am I going wrong?[came in without the rule settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r9rO.jpg)

[image: this how it the rules were set]
This is the Attribute file:
[image: attribute file]
Rule1
[image: Rule1]
Rule2
[image: Rule2]

Comment: Always add the software you use: QGIS, I guess from your screenshot?

Comment: QGIS Zurich 3.81.2

Comment: Does the layer where you want to apply the qml has the same fields invoked in the qml file rules? What I mean is that if your rule ask for a specific field (whose name is elevation, for instance) and that field do no exist in the file you want to apply the rule...it will not do anything. Is that the case?

Comment: Did you manually displace the label ?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same Shapefile/Attributes so exact match to Rules

Comment: By trial and error found - Load in Shapefile, into a new Project same CRS, comes in with Style .gml with the two rules in place and with correct settings as my source file. In my case Rule 1 with a y= -2.00 and Rule2 with y= 2.50.  It displays as above (which is not the same as the source Project). However if I go into Properties Label, select Rule2 and change the displacement to y= 3.50 and Apply they spring back into place. Bizarre? Or a Coding Error?

Comment: Without data examples and your styles we can't answer your questions.

Comment: so I added them then......nothing